# How to search an Array for a string

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a hotel database program that has a search function whereby the user can type a name that is staying in the hotel and the program will display the room number for that person. The code below does recognize when the name entered is the same as an existing name in the program, however it also comes up with an error every time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at hotel.Hotel.findroom(Hotel.java:113)
at hotel.Hotel.main(Hotel.java:51)
Java Result: 1
```

I have also left question marks '???' in the code at the bottom as I have no idea how to get the program to display the room number of the matching name.

```
public class Hotel {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String roomName;
    int roomNum = 0;
    String[] hotel = new String[12];

    initialise(hotel);   

    while ( roomNum  < 11 )

    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter command : ");
        command = input.next();

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'a') {
            addcustomer(hotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'v') {
            viewoccupants(hotel);
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'e') {
            emptyrooms(hotel);

        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'd') {
            deleteroom(hotel);  
        }    

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'f') {
            findroom(hotel);  
        }    
    }
}

 private static void initialise( String hotelRef[] ) {
     for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++ ) hotelRef[x] = "e";
     System.out.println( "initilise ");
  }

private static void viewoccupants(String[] hotel) {
         for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++ )
          {
           System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + hotel[x]);
         }
}

private static void addcustomer(String[] hotel) {
    String roomName;
    int roomNum;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter room number (0-10) or 11 to stop:" ) ;
    roomNum = input.nextInt();
    if (roomNum<11) {
        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum +" :" ) ;
        roomName = input.next();
        hotel[roomNum] = roomName ;   
    }
    else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void emptyrooms(String[] hotel) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++ )
          {
           if (hotel[x].equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
         }
}

private static void deleteroom(String[] hotel) {
    String x = "e";
    int roomNum;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter room to be vacated: " );
    roomNum = input.nextInt();
    if (roomNum<11) {
        hotel[roomNum] = x;   
    }
    else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void findroom(String[] hotel) {
    String roomName;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name: " ) ;
    roomName = input.next();


    for(int i = 0; i < hotel.length; i++){
        if(hotel[i].equals(roomName)){
            System.out.println(roomName + " is located in room " + i);
        }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you want to tell us what the error is? ;)

Comment: How is the room number allocation represented in your code?

Comment: What is the room number supposed to be? The index in the array? In that case don't use foreach, use a simple for loop. Then `i` will be the room number. `for(int i=0; i < hotel.length; ++i) { ... }`

Comment: You have array of Hotel, that means you are doing this for so many hotels?

Comment: Hmm, you are comparing `hotel` with `roomName`, is that ok?

Comment: Secondly for your search a Map would be more suirable, you will be provided with fast search, but only by one property.

Comment: What is the argument of the function (String array of Hotel or String array of room)?

Comment: You can create Map<String, Integer> where String will be roomname and Integer will be room number. compare with user input and display the room number from Map

Comment: It seems you shall post ur full code

Comment: No @Prashant. He should create Map<Hotel,List<Room>>. so that a hotel can have many rooms

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran i thought hotel is having simply room-name!! if it so then yours is fine :)

Comment: If a Hotel has only one room, then there is no point of having Hotel. only he can use rooms and not array of hotel

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran : i don't think he is clear with question and solution.

Comment: Change String[] hotel to String [] rooms. sounds meaningless. thats what we all confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your problem. you need to declare the String[] hotel or String[] rooms as the global member. The scope of the String[] hotel would have been gone when the function execution is completed if you are using in another function or in main then it will be a different String array. So only you will be getting **NPE**. So your code should be like below,

```
public class Hotel {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
private static String[] hotel= new String[11];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String roomName;
    int roomNum = 0;
    initialise();   

    while ( roomNum  < 11 )

    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter command : ");
        command = input.next();

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'a') {
            addcustomer();
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'v') {
            viewoccupants();
        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'e') {
            emptyrooms();

        }

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'd') {
            deleteroom();  
        }    

        if (command.charAt(0) == 'f') {
            findroom();  
        }    
    }
}

 private static void initialise( ) {
     for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++ ) hotel[x] = "e";
     System.out.println( "initilise ");
  }

private static void viewoccupants() {
         for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++ )
          {
           System.out.println("room " + x + " occupied by " + hotel[x]);
         }
}

private static void addcustomer() {
    String roomName;
    int roomNum;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter room number (0-10) or 11 to stop:" ) ;
    roomNum = input.nextInt();
    if (roomNum<11) {
        System.out.println("Enter name for room " + roomNum +" :" ) ;
        roomName = input.next();
        hotel[roomNum] = roomName ;   
    }
    else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void emptyrooms() {
    for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++ )
          {
           if (hotel[x].equals("e"))System.out.println("room " + x + " is empty");
         }
}

private static void deleteroom() {
    String x = "e";
    int roomNum;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter room to be vacated: " );
    roomNum = input.nextInt();
    if (roomNum<11) {
        hotel[roomNum] = x;   
    }
    else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private static void findroom() {
    String roomName;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name: " ) ;
    roomName = input.next();


    for(int i = 0; i < hotel.length; i++){
        if(hotel[i].equals(roomName)){
            System.out.println(roomName + " is located in room " + i);
        }
     }
   }
```

}

Output:

```
initilise 
Enter command : 1
Enter command : a
Enter room number (0-10) or 11 to stop:
1
Enter name for room 1 :
kalai
Enter command : f
Enter name: 
kalai
kalai is located in room 1
Enter command :
```

Comment: Can you please explain the 'if' statement in your 'for' loop at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Now Check the code.i have changed the declaration of the String[]. it will be easily understandable

Comment: If you found this answer is working for you, kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

you also could use lambda in java.

```
int i = 0;
hotel.asList().forEach(i++ -> s==roomName -> System.out.println(n " is located in room " + i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a null pointer because you didn't initialize the last string inside hotel[]. Either you do that or you swap the object and parameter in function equals inside the loop in the findroom function. (roomname.equals(hotel[i])).

The problem originates because you created an array of 12 elements but then you always cicle index from 0 to 10, that is 11 elements, except in the find function where you cicle through the length of the array, that is 12 elements.

Always use "for(int i = 0; i < hotel.length; i++)" to cicle through your array.